# What are some best tools out there to analyze DRAM access pattern?

Tags: memory-management, analysis, performancecounter

I want to analyze the memory access patterns (DRAM Accesses and not CPU cache) of a program. For instance, DRAM accesses performed by a program, DRAM hits, DRAM misses, etc. Is there any tool that could help to get such information?

Comment: What do you mean by a DRAM miss? Do you mean page faults?

Comment: And what OS are you targeting? pref should be able to do page faults on linux.

Comment: I am targeting Linux. Regarding DRAM miss, I am looking for a tool that helps analyze the amount of data accessed by a function/kernel from DRAM and Storage. Looking at page hits and page misses is one way of doing that. However, it does not cover data read by explicit IO calls. Is there any tool to capture such information at the granularity of the kernel/function?

Comment: There are tools that give you patterns of calls to read/write (strace) but I'm not aware of anything that combines them as the relationship between process memory usage and IO calls is completely application specific.

Comment: ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).